# Large Sparse Symmetric Inverse

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, inverse

Nowadays, I'm writing a paper about graph processing.

In experiments on my paper, I wanna write a scalability issue of my algorithm.

the performance of algorithm depends on the inverse operation.

the performance of Matlab inv function is really good on perspective of execution time,

but I don't know the detail algorithm used in Matlab inv function. Is it linear? n log n? n^2? I don't know.

Is there anyone who knows the Matlab inv algorithm in detail? I mean, the name of the algorithm or time complexity.

Thank you.

Comment: Matlab uses the [MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl), so most likely the `inv` function uses the LU decomposition to calculate the inverse of a matrix.

Comment: gire // Do you know computational time of inv function?